# How to clear Billing for data after emptying Shopping Cart

Tags: magento-1.7, onepage-checkout, billing

I have a requirement to clear completed form fields in Magento shopping cart if the cart is emptied. At the moment I have enabled persistent shopping cart but if the cart is emptied after customer info has been entered in the billing address fields etc I need to somehow clear the form also.

I have tried adding:

```
//session_destroy();
```

To my EmpyCart controller but it doesn't work

```
<?php

class MyModule_EmptyCart_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        //Get cart helper
        $cartHelper = Mage::helper('checkout/cart');

        //Get all items from cart
        $items = $cartHelper->getCart()->getItems();

        //Loop through all of cart items
        foreach ($items as $item) {
            $itemId = $item->getItemId();
            //Remove items, one by one
            $cartHelper->getCart()->removeItem($itemId)->save();
        }

        //Redirect back to cart or wherever ou wish
        $this->_redirect('checkout/cart');
            Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->clear();
    }

    public function addAllAction()
    {
        //Get cart helper

        $cartHelper = Mage::helper('checkout/cart');

        //Get all items from cart
        $items = $cartHelper->getCart()->getItems();

        //Loop through all of cart items
        foreach ($items as $item) {
            $itemId = $item->getItemId();
            //Remove items, one by one
            $cartHelper->getCart()->removeItem($itemId)->save();
        }

        //Redirect back to cart or wherever ou wish
        $this->_redirect('checkout/cart');
            Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->clear();
    }
}
```

Is there a simpler way to empty the fields without disabling persistence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try clearing the checkout session.

```
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->clear();
```

Comment: Right first time!